# MySQL dump data from specific time frame

Tags: mysql

We have a huge database. For testing we want to have a production dump on our developer systems. But we can't and won't take the complete production db.

Is there a way to create a dump from mysql which for some tables only contains values newer then X and for some tables (like our country table) the complete table?

I already found the --where option for mysqldump to specify this for the dump of one table to a specific time frame, but this would mean a lot of work, because I need to do this for all tables and at the end combine the different dumps to one file again

Answer (score 0):

Why are u not copying directly server to server.
Use Sqlyog for this.

In sqlyog, there is a option for copy database to other server.

Comment: SQLyog is only available for Windows we work in a Mac / Linux environment 

This job should be executed every night by our build server to prepare this for our test environment